# Counting sort running time

Tags: sorting, counting

The code fragment below from this [link](http://opendatastructures.org/ods-java/11_2_Counting_Sort_Radix_So.html)

```
int[] countingSort(int[] a, int k) {
        int c[] = new int[k];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)    //{1}
            c[a[i]]++;
        for (int i = 1; i < k; i++)           //{2}
            c[i] += c[i-1];
        int b[] = new int[a.length];
        for (int i = a.length-1; i >= 0; i--) //{3}
            b[--c[a[i]]] = a[i];
        return b;
}
```

It states that the running time is O(n+k) time .k is the range of input 
 array a .

Can anyone explain why the running  time is O(n+k). ?

If we look at the code fragment and see that the {1} for loop runs in n time , {2} runs in K time and the third runs in also n time So total run time should be O(2n+k) time . Is my calculation incorrect? Is the constant 2 ignored here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation is also correct, because `O(2n+k) = O(n+k)`.

For time complexity, only the polynomial degree is important, not the coefficients.

So; `O(n) = O(2n) = O(3n) .... = O(xn)`

Please read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Linear_time